# PowerDNS and ISP DNS server

Tags: powerdns

I'm using PowerDNS instance to serve my own domains. All clients in my network are using this DNS server.

How can I configure PowerDNS to query my ISP's DNS servers (for that domains that I don't know)? Is this the right way?

```
recursor=8.8.8.8:53
allow-recursion=10.0.0.0/8
```

Is it possible to specify multiple DNS servers? For example 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is essentially correct although for the default DNS port the `:53` can be omitted.

```
recursor=8.8.8.8
allow-recursion=10.0.0.0/8
```

Only a single server is supported as far as I'm aware, probably because the PowerDNS project is in agreement that it is considered a bad idea to combine an Authoritative nameserver with Recursing nameserver role as the [manual](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/recursion/) states:

> **Warning**: Using `recursor` is **NOT RECOMMENDED** as it comes with many potentially nasty surprise. Background: http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/separation.html

Comment: Thank you. I don't get why PowerDNS does not recommend it, because I want to use one DNS server and be able to resolve all hosts.. BIND supports it with `forwarders`.

Comment: @Xdg It goes against best practices even in BIND land, because the problems are not specific to the choice of DNS product. Please read the link that was included above.

Comment: Okay. So I have to flip it over - point client to recursive DNS and that DNS point to my authoritative PowerDNS? Because if I would point client to two DNS, there would be timeouts.

Comment: Yep that is the recommended way (from a pure DNS perspective). Assign your clients the caching, recursing nameservers. You may need to configure those with a hint on where to find the authoritative nameservers for your internal zones if those can't found through the normal DNS delegation method.